# how to connect to remote oracle database using System.Data.OracleClient in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am building a tool using visual studio 2008 and i want to connect to remote oracle database whose details is given below:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@chi-sunv490-01.harcourt-elearning.com:1521:ELTCPR1
USER NAME: rdadmin
pwd: rdadmin
```

please tell me the softwares which are required to be installed to make this connection and please give me the connection string.

Comment: See: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle

Comment: You just didn't give us the real connectionstring together with the credentials, did you?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a TNS enry in your machine to access the oracle.

https://peking.ithaca.edu:8250/portal/page/portal/TOPLEVELPAGES/ARGUS_HOME_PG/TAB59/argus_recource_center/INSGNG01.pdf

Also please note that the microsoft deprecated the `System.Data.OracleClient`.

So it is better to use ODP components.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html